# Can't find formula to calculate resistor values for a BQ34Z100

Tags: resistors, lithium-ion, texas-instruments, bms, fuel-gauge

I am designing a BMS board using the BQ34Z10 fuel gauge IC.

From the datasheet [BQ34Z100 datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/bq34z100.pdf?ts=1655375272469&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252FBQ34Z100) figure 8-3

[image]

I am unable to figure out how to calculate values for R2,R3,R4.
I am designing the system for a lithium ion battery of 60V and 4A.

Answer (score 0):

To calculate R3 we must define a useful current through D7. We want to keep the current drawn from the battery as low as posible, so let's set 100 µA here. This is not optimal for the Z diode precision but acceptable. U(R3) = 60 V - 5.6 V = 54.4 V, R3 = 54.4 V / 100 µA = 544 kohm, next lower E6 value is 470 kohm, taken. Verify that the voltage across D7 will be close to 5.6 V. Use a lower value for R3 if the Z leakage current is too high.

R2 and R4 should be chosen to deliver about 7 V Ugs to Q5. There is room in both directions when the battery voltage changes. The datasheet sets R2 = 100 kohm. We take that as is, because Cgs of Q5 must match.

R4 = ((60 V / 7 V) - 1) * 100 kohm = 757 kohm, we take 680 kohm from E6 series